# VirtualHost with RewriteRule and alias Apache not working

Tags: apache, virtualhost

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName abc.example.com
 ServerAlias abc.example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/abc

 RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/adl/$
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
    RewriteRule ^ /index.html
</VirtualHost>

alias /adl /opt/dl
```

I have a virtual host setup like this and it works perfectly fine. Now I want if there is **/adl** in the path that rewrite rule should not applied and I have a alias for it directed to a path in my machine directory structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it like the way below

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName walton2.biz-motion.com
 ServerAlias walton2.biz-motion.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/fmcg

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/?(adl)($|/) - [L]    
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 RewriteRule ^ /index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Posted it because if anyone face this.